# "Unable to connect to remote server" error getting in production server when calling eSendex SMS service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, networking, firewall, web-application-firewall

I am using eSendex SMS service to send SMS in our project. We have installed eSendex dot net SDK to call SMS service.We are able to send the SMS from dev environment and from our preprod server as well.We moved changes to production but when we try send SMS from production we are getting issue as 'unable to connect to remote server'. Since we are using esendex dot net SDK we dont know what is the remote server is. I am suspecting our production firewall is blocking to send the request to eSendex service.
Could anybody help me to provide the solution ?

Regards
Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a firewall issue. It should work by whitelisting the Esendex IP range. You could contact the Esendex support team for this information via support@esendex.com.
hope that helps.
Fred